# Pylint with pyspark throws incorrect warning

Tags: pyspark, pylint

i would like to use pylint. But when i applied it to my code, which uses pyspark, I got warning "drop_duplicates is not callable". if i change my code from "drop_duplicates" to "dropDuplicates", the warning disappears. How to fix it without changing whole code? I think drop_duplicates is more python-style. I tried to add pyspark-stubs, but it doenst help.

Answer (score 5):

PySpark is a nightmare to deal with when it comes to linting (even with stubs) because of the JVM generated members.

If you plan to ignore those you have two options:

1. Add the following to `.pylintrc` file in your project root and make sure your linter is configured to pick it up:

```
extension-pkg-whitelist=pyspark
generated-members=pyspark.*
ignored-modules=pyspark.sql.functions
```

2. Whenever you run lint, run it with the following parameters:

```
pylint -j 0 --ignored-modules=pyspark.sql.functions --extension-pkg-whitelist=pyspark --generated-members=pyspark.*
```

Hope this helps.